# Executed .net methods logging on some servers and not others

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

A few years ago I inherited a intranet hosted .net web application that my company installs onto customer owned servers. The application is hosted through IIS, and it appears the architects utilized log4net to handled the logging which is printed to txt log files.

Now, for some reason, on ***some*** customer servers, certain files will not print their logs as is expected, and yes, this code is being executed, as their behavior is being carried out without issue. The files that don't print are consistent across unrelated customer servers, and the same files always dont print. To be clear, methods from files A and B will both always print logs on my test machine and some customer servers, but a set of different customer servers will all only print logs from file A and not from B.

For example, when dispensing a fluid through the application (the software is for fluid management), the code goes through an Execute() method, which calls a Start() method. It is impossible for the Start() method to be called without the Execute() method succesfully completeing its logic and therefore printing logs. On the set of servers that are not functioning properly, we will see 0 logs from the Execute method, but the Start() method will print as expected once it is called.

All of these logs are of the debug priority level, and are executed the same.

As I have stated, I am running the same version of software on my test machine, and all of these logs print as they should. I even backed up a problem servers DB and set it up on mine, and my machine still logged properly.

The above leads me to believe that the issue is not with the software code or anything with the way the sites are configured through the application, and the consistency of the issue doesnt lead me to beleive that there is some buffer or congestion issue with the logs.

Does anyone have any thoughts or leads as what may be causing this?

Here is the Log4Net configuration found in the web.config of a problem server, which is identical to what is on my working machine:

```
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="C:\lfc\web-dashboard.log" />
        <appendToFile value="false" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="14" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%method] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%method] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%method] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Can you show the log4net configuration?  Not the one you THINK is on the server, but the one that is ACTUALLY on the server.  It could be a permission issue (the server can't write log files to the folder given).

Comment: I added what we have in the web.config of a problem server, but it is identical to what I have on my working machine.

Comment: I vaguely remember an issue I had once, where the required log4net DLLs weren't installed as part of the deployment, but someone had installed them manually on some servers.  I'm guessing one of the appenders is not installed.  See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug for details on how to show config errors at start up.

Comment: Thank you, that may be of some help. Ill look into it.